# manipulation of a variable containing large data

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory

in python, i am using a variable to store a large amount of data - about 1GB. i do various operations on this data including truncating it. i also need to do these operations across multiple functions - truncating etc, that is. it seems to me that this is a legitimate use of a global variable since passing the variable between functions as a local variable would involve duplication in memory and therefore be slower. it would also be hard for me to break the variable down into smaller chunks since the data is not a constant length.

can someone tell me if using a global variable is the right way to go about this? or is there a better way?

here is some basic example code for reference:

```
fp = open(filename, 'rb')
bytes = fp.read(1000000000)

def ops1():
  global bytes
  parsed = {}
  i = 0
  while len(bytes):
    parsed[i] = bytes[ : 400]
    bytes = bytes[400 :] # truncate
    parsed[i + 1] = ops2()
    i += 2
    ...more truncating and parsing...

def ops2():
  global bytes
  ...more truncating and parsing...

ops1()
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that calling functions causes copying?

Comment: my own imagination :P my reasoning was: (1) a function that modifies a variable locally without returning it must create a copy, (2) the python interpreter does not look ahead to see if a function returns a variable, (3) therefore python must automatically create a copy of local variables whenever they are modified within a function.
if (2) is wrong then (3) will also be wrong. from what you are saying it sounds like the python interpreter does check to see if a function returns the local variable to decide whether to copy this variable or not?

Comment: Well, I see where you're coming from. In fact, there is copying under the hood, because python is call-by-value. However, what is copied is not the underlying data, but rather *the reference to the object*. The actual data resides on the heap, and is not copied by the function call. Thus, properly speaking variables only ever hold references to values, rather than values.

Answer (score 3):

Python passes **references** around; parameters and local variables, as long as you do not create large new local values (through rebinding or copying), local vs. global makes *no difference*.

A function certainly never is passed a new copy of the value, unless you explicitly first create a copy and then pass *that* to a function.

Making `bytes` a parameter to your functions instead of using a global would make no difference in memory use, but *would* make dereferencing the name *faster* (ever so slightly).

As `bytes` is a list, you can always manipulate it *in place*; you can delete indices directly from it, or assign to the identity slice to not rebind but shrink the list itself:

```
del bytes[:400]  # remove first 400 elements
```

or

```
bytes[:] = bytes[400:]  # replace *all* indices in `bytes` with everything but the first 400
```

Comment: say only local variables were to be used, if `bytes` is passed to `ops2` and `ops2` modifies `bytes` then surely `ops1` must have a different local value for `bytes`? otherwise `bytes` would be a global variable, but variables are local by default in python.

Comment: No, because as martijn says, the *reference* is passed. If ops2 modifies it, then ops1 will see the same changes.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but both local variables will reference the same memory location only if `ops2` returns the `bytes` variable? if so then python must look ahead before modifying the `bytes` variable to see if it gets returned to the scope of `ops1`. i guess my assumption was that python was not so smart ;)

Comment: @mulllhausen: I see what you mean, but you can manipulate a list object in-place. Examples given.